# How to push Docker image to ECR in Jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, docker-image, amazon-ecr

I am working with Jenkins. I am trying to push image to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/). I am using local Docker to build the images.

Below is my Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat  'docker build -t sampleapp -f SampleApp/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
        stage('Push image') {
         steps {
           withDockerRegistry([url: "https://536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository",credentialsId: "ecr:ap-southeast-2:demo-ecr-credentials"]) {
           bat 'docker push sampleapp:latest'
               }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am able to build and create an image. In the second stage, I am facing the issues. I am getting the below error:

> ```
> $ docker login -u AWS -p ******** https://536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository
>
> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.  
> Login Succeeded
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\SampleAppPipeLine>docker push sampleapp:latest 
> The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/sampleapp]
> a160522d6d0e: Preparing
> 2e2c2606bd45: Preparing
> 9b0a482c69b1: Preparing
> 995a0cc6a5f6: Preparing
> c1b55dcb46c2: Preparing
> cf5b3c6798f7: Preparing
> cf5b3c6798f7: Waiting
>     
> denied: requested access to the resource is denied
> ```

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I did not see any error in the logs?

Comment: Hi process apparently never started message it will display and stucks. Also in work space templ folder will get create and file script.sh will get create. Inside script.sh I can see docker tag sampleapp 536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sampleapp:latest

Comment: May I know http://536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sampleapp:latest this is the url supposed to be inside script.sh?

Comment: yes if this your AWS ECR url

Comment: But where to change this?  docker.withRegistry already I gave with https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default repository of `docker.io` is being `hardcode` is : `docker.io/library/`

So for AWS ECR repo, you should :

```
docker build -t test-repository .
```

> docker tag test-repository:latest
>   536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository:latest

```
docker push 536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository:latest
```

Make sure `test-repository` repo is already create on ECR.

Comment: I added         bat 'docker push https://536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository/sampleapp:latest' and getting invalid reference format error

Comment: `536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository:latest`  is this? right ?

Comment: Yes this is the ECR repo url

Comment: did you `tag` for image : `docker tag latest aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app`

Comment: Yeah in Build stage. I have uploaded my jenkins file code above

Comment: have you created `test-repository` repo on AWS ?

Comment: Yes with  Principal *

Comment: what does it mean `Principal *` ,just updated the answer.

Comment: I added above code and getting error Error response from daemon: No such image: latest:latest. So it is looking image latest:latest?

Comment: my app name is sampleapp so it should be sampleapp:latest?

Comment: I am not able to understand this step docker build -t test-repository . why test-repository?

Comment: change `test-repository ` to `sampleapp` and `docker tag sampleapp:latest 536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sampleapp:latest`

Comment: `docker push 536703334988.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sampleapp:latest` , Make sure `sampleapp` repo is already create on ECR.

Comment: Above code works but may I know how to include build number with tag?

Comment: you can set `$buildnumber` as your tag

Comment: docker build -t $buildnumber -f SampleApp/Dockerfile . this way?

Comment: please let try it

Comment: Hi just wondering if this script is the Declarative pipeline? and how to define aws credential in this file before push it to ecr?

Comment: in `jenkins` server ,configure `~/.aws/config` for aws credetial